# Get back data from ElasticSearch

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I'm new to ELK. We have a Spring Boot backend on a dedicated AWS instance. We have ELK stack on another instance (To the outside world only Kibana is available). Information gathering to ELK is carried out via Amazon SQS.

These information include logs and some business history about user (registration, any other action, etc).

In this case, I have a question. Is it possible to get back information by action, by user and use it in the backend responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to use data present in Elasticsearch to be available to spring boot application. It is definitely possible. You will need to open up elasticsearch port on elasticsearch machine to specifically to EC2 instance on which spring boot is running. How to open port will depend on if they are on same vpc, different vpc, different aws account etc. Once port is open, you can either use [Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/) or just rest calls to access elasticsearch api.